# Was NYSE outage on July 8th, 2015 a result of a cyber attack?

Tags: finance, hacking

New York Stock Exchange [claims](https://twitter.com/NYSE/status/618818929906085888) that the downtime was due *"internal technical issue"* and denies claims of cyber attack.

[image]

On the other hand, allegedly few hours prior to the outage Anonymous [has tweeted](https://twitter.com/YourAnonNews/status/618626955433349120):

> Wonder if tomorrow is going to be bad for Wall Street.... we can only hope.

[image]

Was the outage result of Anonymous cyber attack?

Comment: I thought the FBI already declared that the NYSE outage was not a cyber attack, thus it's not under  active investigation? The NYSE already reported that the problem was [due to a software update](http://www.nydailynews.com/news/national/software-update-caused-nyse-trading-halt-article-1.2286408) so I don't think there's going to be any official investigative report. So I'm not sure there's any reason to close this question, it can be answered based on the explanation released by the NYSE.

Comment: @Johnny if the only thing you can reference is the primary source of the question, then there is no question to answer in the first place.

Comment: It may be true that he hasn't cited any credible sources to back his claim, but that's not the reason stated for putting the question on hold - using the right "hold" reason is important so the question can be improved to make it a suitable site. There are plenty of conspiracy theories about the NYSE (and UAL) outage, so I think a well written question with sources would be a valuable addition to this site.

Comment: @Johnny the FBI declared that they won't investigate, because the NYSE declared that it was not cyber attack. So it's not like the FBI actually checked anything. It's all based on NYSE's denial. OTOH financial institutions are know for doing everything in their power to sweep cyber attacks under the rug. [Example](http://www.pymnts.com/news/2015/how-100-banks-got-hacked-and-lost-900-million/)

Comment: @vartec - I don't disagree with you, there was a lot of speculation about a cyber attack when the outage happened, and I think this is a valid question for this site if some credible sources to back a cyberattack can be quoted. In any case, I think the "hold" reason is incorrect, since I'm not aware of any official investigation since the official explanation is that it was just a technical glitch.